# The $n=0$ term in the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$

Tags: real-analysis, notation, power-series

This question is about the **definition** and **notation** for the $0^{th}$ term of the power series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$$

There are two possible ways to interpret this term:

1) It is just a short way to write $a_0=$ const, **independent** on $x$.

2) It is understood as a limit $\lim_{n \to 0} a_n x^n$, or something else entirerly, since $n$ is an integer. In any way, it **might depend** on $x$.

> So what is the correct definition?

The problem in the second case arises not only for $x \to 0$ as someone might think. What about a more general case of $x$ being complex, or a dual number, or a matrix?

There is a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1585105/269624), but I did not find the answer illuminating.

Comment: For integer exponents, $x^0 = 1$ for all $x$ is unproblematic. You only get a problem at $0^0$ if you consider non-integral exponents, and let base and exponent both vary.

Comment: I think it just come straight from polynomials (seen as sequences with finite support).

Comment: @DanielFischer, what about $x$ being a matrix, an operator, or any other general object with defined integer exponentiation?

Comment: You have a problem if the set of objects under consideration doesn't contain a multiplicative identity. If multiplication isn't associative, that might lead to problems regarding exponentiation too. If you have a $1$, and multiplication is associative, then defining $x^0 = 1$ doesn't lead to problems I know of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second interpretation doesn't make any sense.

In algebra, one way to view a [formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series) is as an infinite ordered sequence of numbers. In this case, the powers of the variable are used only to indicate the order of the coefficients. The coefficient of $x^5$ is just the fifth term in the sequence, while the coefficient of $x^0$ is the zeroth term.

In analysis, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$, if the limit exists at all, is understood as nothing but

$$a_0\cdot 1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n x^n$$
where $1$ is the "identity" according to what context you are talking about.

The notation $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ is just for convenience. I don't think there is anything deep there.

Comment: I would be very grateful if you provided source(s) with this definition of the 0 term. I agree that the second option doesn't make sense, that's why I'd rather go with the first

Comment: @YuriyS What kind of source are you looking for? This is the kind of thing that's so common that people don't even bother writing it down (just like an anatomy textbook probably wouldn't bother explaining that a typical human has two hands...). [Look at Wikipedia for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series): nothing makes sense unless you assume $x^0 = 1$, and then everything makes sense...

Comment: I have not seen a book giving such *definition* before. It is just the way how people would understand the notation. You might take a look at *Complex Analysis* (p38) by Ahlfors.

Comment: "It’s also worth bearing in mind that notation is ultimately an artificial human invention, rather than an innate feature of the mathematics one is working on." as Terry Tao once said.