# Exponential series representation

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, power-series

It is well known that the exponential function can be represented as follows:

$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
However, the right hand side is not defined at $x=0$ due to $n=0$. Is it wrong? should we use  this one:
$$e^x=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\text{?}$$

Comment: When evaluating power series or polynomials, $0^0=1.$ Some people leave $0^0$ undefined, but I prefer to define it as $1.$ There is no paradox in this definition - it doesn’t break math to define it this way.

Comment: In *any* power series $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ this issue would come up, but the convention is that in such a case $0^0$ is regarded as $1.$ Your second expression is equivalent to doing that, but I don't think mathematicians would worry about the issue.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Google calculator has solved this with the new update: If we include $0 ^ 0$, the result will be $1$ or undefined.

Comment: @coffeemath : It is not a mere convention; it is demostrably the only way that makes sense.

Comment: @lonestudent in calculators, it actually makes sense for $0^0$ to be undefined, because numbers in calculators really represent the number plus-or-minus an error. But anywhere which has integer types should have $x^0=1$ be defined for all numbers $x$ when the $0$ in the exponent is an integer.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  Thank you for your points. As far as I remember, with the old update, google calculator was defined it as $0 ^ 0 = 1$.  But with the newest update, google changed that.  If we write $0 ^ 0$ we will get the result  "$1$ or undefined".  Even more interesting, the "online google calculator" still defines it as $0 ^ 0 = 1$.  I just wanted to add.  You probably noticed it too..  https://www.google.com/search?q=0%5E0+calculator&oq=0%5E0&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j6j35i39j0l2.3367j0j4&client=ms-android-hmd-rev2&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't $\exp(x)$ have a gap at $x=0?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3560746/why-doesnt-expx-have-a-gap-at-x-0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, $0!=1.$ This is not in dispute. It is just the definition. There are reasons for the definition, but I won’t go into them here.

This example is one of many reasons to define $0^0=1.$ There are several other reasons, but there are other questions covering that on this site.

I’ll just add that there is no problem with defining $0^0=1.$ It doesn’t lead to paradoxes, just discontinuities.

That said, even if we left $0^0$ undefined, we’d still treat $e^0=1$ using the standard power series notation. The notation is too convenient.

Do we really want to write:

> If $$f(x)=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n$$ then $$f’(x)=1\cdot a_1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+1)a_{n+1}x^n?$$

That hides the pattern. You have to read carefully to realize the constant term follows the pattern of the other terms.

It would be notation that obscures rather than clarifies.

Answer (score 1):

In this context one should define $0^0=1$ and $0!=1$ because $\displaystyle \prod_{x\,\in\,\varnothing} x = 1.$

Proof:
$$
\prod_{x\,\in\,A} x = \prod_{x\,\in\,A\,\cup\,\varnothing} x = \prod_{x\,\in\,A }x \cdot \prod_{x\,\in\,\varnothing} x.
$$
Now divide both sides by the leftmost expression. $\qquad\blacksquare$

Comment: +1 But... That isn’t really “proof” if we could just leave $$\prod_{x\in\emptyset} x$$ undefined. It does give a reason that the only good definition definition is $1$ if we define it.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : The fact that this isn't really a proof is one of the deficiencies or present-day understanding of logic.